# expected string/class/function got object

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to implement React-Navigation in my application.
When I run the app it crashes with the error:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string or class/function but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
```

I searched here but any solution I tried did not work.
This is my code:

index:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Root } from './config/router';

class Stylelist extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Root />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Stylelist;
```

Router:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Login from '../views/Login';

export const Root = StackNavigator({
  Login:{
    screen: Login,
  },
  Register:{
    screen: Register,
    navigationOptions:{
      title: 'Registertion'
    }
  }
});
```

Login:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Image, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, KeyboardAvoidingView, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

//TODO: Change StatusBar color.
export default class Login extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return(
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar
          barStyle="light-content">
        </StatusBar>
        <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
          <Image
          style={styles.logoImg}
          />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.formContainer}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="email"
            placeholderTextColor="#315D49"
            returnKeyType="next"
            onSubmitEditing={()=> this.passwordInput.focus()}
            keyboardType="email-address"
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
            color="#315D49"
            style={styles.input} />
          <TextInput
            placeholder="password"
            placeholderTextColor="#315D49"
            secureTextEntry={true}
            returnKeyType="go"
            ref={(input)=> this.passwordInput = input}
            color="#315D49"
            style={styles.input} />
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
              LOGIN
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.signupContainer} onPress={()=>navigate('Register')}>
            <Text style={styles.signupText}>
              Don't have an account yet?
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}
```

Register:

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
  export default class Register extends Component{
    render(){
      return(
         <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>
              Register page.
            </Text>
         </View>
      );
    }
  }

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container:{
       flex: 1,
     }
 });
```

index.ios.js:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import Stylelist from './index';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Stylelist', () => Stylelist);
```

The problem seems to be in in index. but anything I tried did not work.
any help?

Answer (score 0):

From the basic understanding that I have, taking into account the examples on the React Navigation website, your `StackNavigator` object should be the root component that is registered to `AppRegistry`. It cannot be nested in a `View` or another component. So, if you change delete your `index` file, and change your `index.ios.js` file to this,

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { Root as Stylelist } from './config/router';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Stylelist', () => Stylelist);
```

it should work for you.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and update as soon as possible.